# Dialogflow webhook response is showing not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dialogflow-es

[dialogflow response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgZzX.png)

RawAPIReponse:

```
{
  "responseId": "0e78ce0c-0953-49fa-9f6d-33c34720cc6d-83ffff32",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "test",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "This is a text response",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "linkOutSuggestion": {
          "destinationName": "ad",
          "uri": "https://www.google.be/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/healthbot-xsvrws/agent/intents/91d019fd-7594-459a-bb41-281bea75ac1d",
      "displayName": "webhook test"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 389
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  }
}
```

Fulfillment Response:

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "This is a text response",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "linkOutSuggestion": {
        "destinationName": "ad",
        "uri": "https://www.google.be/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Fullfillmentstatus:

```
Webhook execution successful
```

I m returning webhook response from dotnet mvc api. I have used **Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2** library.

When i am returning below json its working.

```
        string testResponse = @"{
              ""fulfillmentText"": ""This is a text response"",
              ""fulfillmentMessages"": [
                {
                            ""card"":
                            {
                                ""title"": ""card title"",
                                ""subtitle"": ""card text"",
                                ""imageUri"": ""https://assistant.google.com/static/images/molecule/Molecule-Formation-stop.png"",
                                ""buttons"": [
                                {
                                    ""text"": ""button text"",
                                    ""postback"": ""https://assistant.google.com/""
                                }]
                            }
                }]
            }";
```

**I want to use suggestion chips in my project. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a [linkout suggestion](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#SuggestionChipsProperties) to Dialogflow. Link out suggestions are elements for Google Assistant and these aren't supported in the default simulator of Dialogflow.

If you wish to send a suggestion that you can see in the default simulator, have a look at the [suggestion chip](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/rich-responses#suggestion_%E2%87%90_richresponse) in the dialogflow fullfilment library, suggestions in the Dialogflow UI or implement a custom button via [custom payloads](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom) and load this in your own custom chatbot.

Comment: I needed a suggestion chip and found a way.  
{
 
    {
      "payload": {
        "richContent": [
          [
            {
              "type": "chips",
              "options": [
                {
                  "text": "Chip 1"
                },
                {
                  "text": "Chip 2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}